# Application locks up after i remove a function not in use

Tags: xcode

I comment out a function and the application compiles(no errors or warnings) but when I run it, it freezes up and crashes out.  I uncomment the function, not in use, and then the application works fine.

What is the best approach to deal with this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick a breakpoint on the function and see what's calling it.

Comment: I made a call from NSTimer.  I wonder why it compiled with no errors or warnings.

Comment: Were you using a selector? That's the sort of thing that gets sorted out at runtime rather than compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Put a log in the function `NSLog(@"Function Called");` to confirm that it really isn't getting called. Also make sure it isn't declared in any headers.